# How to read merged cell values of an excel file with openpyxl / python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have been trying to read value of a merged cell by using openpyxl module. However, it gives below error:

```
if ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value == q.get(): #and ws.cell(row=i+1, column=j).value == 'tot.':
```

AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object has no attribute 'value'

What do you suggest? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion `MergedCells` have no values: they're only used for putting borders on ranges of merged cells and shouldn't really be considered cells. Use `hasattr(cell, "value")` or `getattr(cell, "value", None)`

Comment: hey can you lease elaborate the answers to use hasattr()
My problem is i want to replicate some part of worksheet to different worksheet which also have the merge cells